# Who has to yield when waiting at the median lane in Florida?

Tags: traffic, florida

It will be best to illustrate it. The red car was turning left from the bottom of the picture and is waiting on the median until the traffic is clear to enter the lane.
The yellow car is coming from the left of the picture after the red car is already there waiting and wants to turn left.

Red car is looking to the right direction to see when no traffic is coming and doesn't even see the yellow car.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Florida Statutes 316.121(1)](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0300-0399/0316/Sections/0316.121.html):

> The driver of a vehicle approaching an intersection shall yield the right-of-way to a vehicle which has entered the intersection from a different highway.

I'm not an expert in Florida traffic law, so I don't know that there aren't other statutes or local by-laws that supercede this one.